# Java GUI application architecture + database, MVC

Tags: java, sql, swing, jpa, model-view-controller

I'm writing applications for warehouse management (this is my first major program in Java). I wonder how to properly plan.

SQL tables: `ORDERS | COMPANY | CATEGORIES |  PRODUCTS | CUSTOMERS`

When you turn on the program, you will have a choice of large buttons on the center of the screen:

- Browse Order
- Add categories
- Add your company
- Products
- Customers

(then these options will be on the bar at the top)

no analogy to the button names will be carried out different functions. The data presented in Table I, and after clicking on a record will have the ability to edit (as I see it), checkboxes - mass removal, the total is the functionality will be duplicated at each option.

The entire application wants to rely on the MVC pattern, but I do not know yet how exactly to divide.

-For mapping want to use JPA

-Singleton pattern will handle the database connection

-Pattern Strategy will support navigation (browse order, add categories, etc)

I wonder now just how to isolate the presentation layer (tables, buttons, etc) from the database layer, I can not see this, maybe because I made a never not such an example. To switch views wants to use CardLayout. I wonder what patterns there are and how to use it more plan.

edit:

Summation:
Which design patterns to use? 
How to efficiently divide it in MVC? 
Using JPA is a good step?
I am looking for examples.

Comment: Ask specific question about exact prroblem you have

Comment: Which design patterns to use? How to efficiently divide it in MVC? I am looking for examples. Using JPA is a good step?

Comment: Using JPA or not has nothing to do with using MVC. MVC is about Single Responsibility. You have a model, which represents the data, a view that represents the Interface, and a Controller which handles interactions with your domain layer. JPA is an API for storing and retrieving Database Entities. Using something like Hibernate (JPA) or Active Reports (jOOQ) or even plain ole JDBC is completely irrelevant to your use of MVC.

Comment: Yes, I know it. I wanted to ask whether the use of the JPA will be a good API for this project.

Comment: So you're aware, asking "Which design patterns to use?" is backwards; you have a solution looking for a problem.  You should be asking "What do I call this thing I implemented that fits my needs?".  For instance, you don't set out to implement a "repository pattern" - instead, you need some way to abstract instance storage/retrieval(/creation), and what ends up implemented follows a pattern similar to other "repositories".

Comment: One of the main things for me is how to implement query whereas a few tables, and writing only one function for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not that specific, so I select only a part of your question.

> how to isolate the presentation layer (tables, buttons, etc) from the
>   database layer

You will probably use **Java Swing** which implements MVC pattern in itself. 
Swing provides GUI elements you can use for your user interfaces. 
Every user interface instance have related actions that corresponds to user actions, such as `click`, `move`, `select`. 
Whenever an action is fired, listeners catch those actions for `Controller`. 
This is where you work on `Model` layer. `Controller` will update the `Model` (in your terms **database layer**). View will be rendered according to the updated `Model`.

For details refer to:

[Official Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

[Simple Representation](http://shulgadim.blogspot.com.tr/2012/01/model-view-controller-mvc-pattern_13.html)

[Good one in terms of MVC simplification](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076632/core-java/mvc-meets-swing.html)

Comment: Yes. I will use Java Swing. I was also wondering how to write functions that will be performed insert, update, for any table. Without duplication of functions and placing them minor changes.

Comment: As you have mentioned, you can use JPA. You will annotate your Model classes for DB access. You can refer to this site [http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html]

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to MVC framework (like Spring MVC) + Apache Velocity templates (in the html code you can use java objects and functions to get what you need) or Java Server Pages. Maybe if you application is small (velocity templates would be enough)

Comment: Thanks for answer. My application will be small. I read about spring. But I do not want to go to the new technology, I want to first learn the basics.

Comment: Simply an advice : Apache velocity is really cool, but for your first application you'd better stick to JSP pages.

Comment: I need and want to do it in a windowed application.